# Is it possible to make polygons using jquery mobile and google maps v3?

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, polygons

Does anyone know if it is possible to make polygons around markers (specifically a radius) using the jQuery Mobile platform and Google maps v3?

I'd like it to somewhat work like this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/mvcfun

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/articles/mvcfun/step3

But formatted for jQuery mobile.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you just want a circle in pixel space, use a [`Symbol`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol) as the `icon` in `MarkerOptions`.

If you want it in real metres, then use a [`Circle`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle) overlay.

I'm not sure what you mean by "formatted for jQuery mobile" - the Google Maps API works fine on desktop *and* mobile - the same code should *just work*.

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris!  What I'm trying to do is to use these circles around markers as well as around the userLocation (which I have now achieved), but I want to create some sort of notification when the userLocation's circle intersects with the markerLocation's circle on the map.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If you're talking about circles on the earth, then all you need to do is calculate the distance between the two points.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I ended up using:  distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerPosition, userLocation); to figure out radius.